# Find/Filter data from multiple parents and multiple child using Lodash

Tags: javascript, json, loops, lodash

My data:

```
[
   {
      "configData":[
         {
            "repoSettings":[
               {
                  "BaseURL":"45df16eb-55f9-48a9-9df8-428984524d7b",
                  "CurrentBranch":"Publish_1522323990",
                  "CurrentHeadSHA":"85c599a6ab3ecf8bfb469479da",
                  "RepositoryId":1528,
                  "RepositoryName":"45df16eb-55f94524d7b"
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "pageSettings":[
               {
                  "PageCss":[

                  ],
                  "PageExternalCss":[

                  ],
                  "PageExternalJs":[

                  ],
                  "PageLayout":"default",
                  "PageMetaInfo":[

                  ],
                  "PageMetacharset":"UTF-8",
                  "PageName":"index.html",
                  "PageSEODescription":"",
                  "PageSEOKeywords":"",
                  "PageSEOTitle":"",
                  "PageScripts":[

                  ],
                  "PageStyles":[

                  ],
                  "partials":[
                     {
                        "Header":"default"
                     },
                     {
                        "Footer":"default"
                     }
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "PageCss":[

                  ],
                  "PageExternalCss":[

                  ],
                  "PageExternalJs":[

                  ],
                  "PageLayout":"default",
                  "PageMetaInfo":[

                  ],
                  "PageMetacharset":"UTF-8",
                  "PageName":"about.html",
                  "PageSEODescription":"",
                  "PageSEOKeywords":"",
                  "PageSEOTitle":"",
                  "PageScripts":[

                  ],
                  "PageStyles":[

                  ],
                  "partials":[
                     {
                        "Header":"default"
                     },
                     {
                        "Footer":"default"
                     },
                     {
                        "Sidebar":"default"
                     }
                  ]
               },
               ,
               {
                  "PageCss":[

                  ],
                  "PageExternalCss":[

                  ],
                  "PageExternalJs":[

                  ],
                  "PageLayout":"default",
                  "PageMetaInfo":[

                  ],
                  "PageMetacharset":"UTF-8",
                  "PageName":"about.html",
                  "PageSEODescription":"",
                  "PageSEOKeywords":"",
                  "PageSEOTitle":"",
                  "PageScripts":[

                  ],
                  "PageStyles":[

                  ],
                  "partials":[
                     {
                        "Header":"default"
                     },
                     {
                        "Footer":"default"
                     },
                     {
                        "Sidebar":"default"
                     },
                     {
                        "MenuBar":"default"
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

In this data, I want to iterate through all objects of pageSettings and inside, all partials array, I want to iterate through all objects and find all indexes of matching condition. 
Let say, I have "Header" key and value "default" pair. Now I want to find in this JSON for all pageSettings objects and for all partials object. If the key-value pair is found, then return true for that pageSettings index.
Is it possible through Lodash? Or can you provide snipp?

Comment: [You Might Not Need Lodash](https://youmightnotneed.com/lodash/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out.
you can use forEach() on the array and try to find out keys and values from partials.

```js
let data = [
   {
      "configData":[
         {
            "repoSettings":[
               {
                  "BaseURL":"45df16eb-55f9-48a9-9df8-428984524d7b",
                  "CurrentBranch":"Publish_1522323990",
                  "CurrentHeadSHA":"85c599a6ab3ecf8bfb469479da",
                  "RepositoryId":1528,
                  "RepositoryName":"45df16eb-55f94524d7b"
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "pageSettings":[
               {
                  "PageCss":[

                  ],
                  "PageExternalCss":[

                  ],
                  "PageExternalJs":[

                  ],
                  "PageLayout":"default",
                  "PageMetaInfo":[

                  ],
                  "PageMetacharset":"UTF-8",
                  "PageName":"index.html",
                  "PageSEODescription":"",
                  "PageSEOKeywords":"",
                  "PageSEOTitle":"",
                  "PageScripts":[

                  ],
                  "PageStyles":[

                  ],
                  "partials":[
                     {
                        "Header":"default"
                     },
                     {
                        "Footer":"default"
                     }
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "PageCss":[

                  ],
                  "PageExternalCss":[

                  ],
                  "PageExternalJs":[

                  ],
                  "PageLayout":"default",
                  "PageMetaInfo":[

                  ],
                  "PageMetacharset":"UTF-8",
                  "PageName":"about.html",
                  "PageSEODescription":"",
                  "PageSEOKeywords":"",
                  "PageSEOTitle":"",
                  "PageScripts":[

                  ],
                  "PageStyles":[

                  ],
                  "partials":[
                     {
                        "Header":"default"
                     },
                     {
                        "Footer":"default"
                     },
                     {
                        "Sidebar":"default"
                     }
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "PageCss":[

                  ],
                  "PageExternalCss":[

                  ],
                  "PageExternalJs":[

                  ],
                  "PageLayout":"default",
                  "PageMetaInfo":[

                  ],
                  "PageMetacharset":"UTF-8",
                  "PageName":"about.html",
                  "PageSEODescription":"",
                  "PageSEOKeywords":"",
                  "PageSEOTitle":"",
                  "PageScripts":[

                  ],
                  "PageStyles":[

                  ],
                  "partials":[
                     {
                        "Header":"default"
                     },
                     {
                        "Footer":"default"
                     },
                     {
                        "Sidebar":"default"
                     },
                     {
                        "MenuBar":"default"
                     }
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "PageCss":[

                  ],
                  "PageExternalCss":[

                  ],
                  "PageExternalJs":[

                  ],
                  "PageLayout":"default",
                  "PageMetaInfo":[

                  ],
                  "PageMetacharset":"UTF-8",
                  "PageName":"about.html",
                  "PageSEODescription":"",
                  "PageSEOKeywords":"",
                  "PageSEOTitle":"",
                  "PageScripts":[

                  ],
                  "PageStyles":[

                  ],
                  "partials":[
                     {
                        "Sidebar":"default"
                     },
                     {
                        "MenuBar":"default"
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]

function find(key, value) {
 let matchingIndex = [];
 data[0].configData[1].pageSettings.forEach((i, settingIndex) => {
    i.partials.forEach(j => {
      let matching = Object.keys(j).filter(k => k === key && j[k] === value);     
      if(matching && matching.length) {
        matchingIndex.push(settingIndex);
      };
    })
 })
 
 console.log('Given values ('+key+','+value+') are found in setting index: '+ matchingIndex);
}

find('Header','default');
find('Sidebar','default')
```